# Spark read csv with commented headers

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I have the following file which I need to read using spark in scala -

```
#Version: 1.0
#Fields: date time location timezone
2018-02-02  07:27:42 US LA
2018-02-02  07:27:42 UK LN
```

I am currently trying to extract the fields using the following the -

```
spark.read.csv(filepath)
```

I am new to spark+scala and wanted to know know is there a better way to extract fields based on the # Fields row at the top of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using *sparkContext's textFile* api to read the text file and then `filter` the *header line*

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("filePath")

val header = rdd
  .filter(line => line.toLowerCase.contains("#fields:"))
  .map(line => line.split(" ").tail)
  .first()
```

That should be it.

Now if you want to create a dataframe then you should *parse* it to form `schema` and then `filter` the *data lines* to form *Rows*. And finally use *SQLContext* to create a *dataframe*

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schema = StructType(header.map(title => StructField(title, StringType, true)))

val dataRdd = rdd.filter(line => !line.contains("#")).map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split(" ")))

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(dataRdd, schema)

df.show(false)
```

This should give you

```
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
|date      |time    |location|timezone|
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
|2018-02-02|07:27:42|US      |LA      |
|2018-02-02|07:27:42|UK      |LN      |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Note: if the file is *tab* delimited, instead of doing

```
line.split(" ")
```

you should be using `\t`

```
line.split("\t")
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample input file "*example.csv*"

```
#Version: 1.0
#Fields: date time location timezone
2018-02-02 07:27:42 US LA
2018-02-02 07:27:42 UK LN
```

*Test.scala*

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.Builder
import org.apache.spark.sql._

import scala.util.Try

object Test extends App {

  // create spark session and sql context
  val builder: Builder = SparkSession.builder.appName("testAvroSpark")
  val sparkSession: SparkSession = builder.master("local[1]").getOrCreate()
  val sc: SparkContext = sparkSession.sparkContext
  val sqlContext: SQLContext = sparkSession.sqlContext

  case class CsvRow(date: String, time: String, location: String, timezone: String)

  // path of your csv file
  val path: String =
    "sample.csv"

  // read csv file and skip firs two lines

  val csvString: Seq[String] =
    sc.textFile(path).toLocalIterator.drop(2).toSeq

  // try to read only valid rows
  val csvRdd: RDD[(String, String, String, String)] =
    sc.parallelize(csvString).flatMap(r =>
      Try {
        val row: Array[String] = r.split(" ")
        CsvRow(row(0), row(1), row(2), row(3))
      }.toOption)
      .map(csvRow => (csvRow.date, csvRow.time, csvRow.location, csvRow.timezone))

  import sqlContext.implicits._

  // make data frame
  val df: DataFrame =
    csvRdd.toDF("date", "time", "location", "timezone")

  // display dataf frame
  df.show()
}
```